# Tastypie Swagger with default configuration gives NoReverseMatch exception, says 'tastypie_swagger' is not a registered namespace

Tags: django, tastypie

Pretty much as it sounds in the title.

I followed the instructions on https://github.com/concentricsky/django-tastypie-swagger

The install seemed to work, but when I go to the URL I set, I get a "NoReverseMatch at /alex/"

u"'tastypie_swagger" is not a registered namespace

And then a more detailed error that looks like

```
    Error during template rendering

    In template /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/thm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie_swagger/templates/tastypie_swagger/index.html, error at line 48
```

u"'tastypie_swagger" is not a registered namespace

And shows a line in a tastypie swagger template that is erroring

Comment: Can we see your urls.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main template in tastypie_swagger uses the url tag with a quoted path, as required by Django 1.5, which is incompatible with earlier versions of Django.

Try adding the following to tastypie_swagger/templates/tastypie_swagger/index.html to make it compatible with Django 1.4

```
(% load url from future %}
```

Add it anywhere prior to the first {% url %} tag in the file. This should get you past the issue until this can be addressed by the module author.

Comment: This was added to the repo yesterday https://github.com/concentricsky/django-tastypie-swagger/commit/44dab3a4d3ce98619c33d0a8f85ae80faddb6980